# input username check unique immediately with django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to realize like this: if I input any character in username input tag I can check the username if unique in server.

I know I can do like this: use javascript + debounce, after user input characters stop 0.5 second, then I send username to server(I can create single view to handle this solution), and if find duplication, I can hint some error near it.

But in fact, I am not only handle the username, I want to handle all of config form, I want to every form's field can be test before send whole form data to server like this.

There may be 100 fields, I dont' want to write a view for every field, so does django-rest-framework support some function? or is there any package suuport it, or somebody have any idea for it??

in fact, I use reactjs, but I don't think it have any relationship with this problem

Comment: If you are checking every field, wouldn't it make sense to validate the whole form at once? It may take a few moments longer, but it's better than hitting your database 100+ times for one form.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no such thing. You'll have to write your own. A non rest entry point that would take a POST including field name and field value and check the unicity in the DB.